# How do I set the precision and scale in SQL (access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a table in Access.

I have the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE Class Enrollement (
   OfferNo            INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY,
   StdNo Text(9) NULL,
  EnrGrade Decimal(2) Percision(8) scale(4) NULL
);
```

EnrGrade needs to be a decimal, Precision of 8, Scale of 4, and 2 decimal places.

The last line of code is not correct.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

Where the first value is the precision (number of decimal digits, followed by scale, or numbers after the decimal)

```
CREATE TABLE ClassEnrollment (
   OfferNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   StdNo Text(9) NULL,
  EnrGrade Decimal(8, 2) NULL
);
```

Comment: Say I wanted to set OfferNo as both a Primary Key and a Foreign Key.  Is that possible?

Comment: Also, Scale and numbers after the decimal are the same thing?

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant by scale, sorry.  If you elaborate more, maybe I can answer your question.

Comment: I guess it would depend what you would want OfferNo to foreign key to. Your current question only has the one table.  You might get a better response making a new question to keep your help separated on the different topics.

Comment: I am not sure what is meant be scale either, our assignment simply states to set the scale to 4.  I have googled to find out what scale is, and there's really no consistency.  Thanks

Comment: After doing a bit more research, the decimal datatype does not exist in Access, why we were told to use it I am not sure.

Comment: @Brandon: "the decimal datatype does not exist in Access" -- your research is faulty :) See Denis Shvydenko's answer about enabling [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0). Then read [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;275561#XSLTH3210121123120121120120): "Decimal data types are new to Microsoft Jet 4.0..."

Answer (score 0):

You must enable [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0). After that in your query you can write:

```
CREATE TABLE Offering (
   OfferNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   StdNo Text(9) NULL,
  EnrGrade Decimal(8,4) NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Precision of 8, Scale of 4, and 2 decimal places

These requirements appear contradictory. A decimal column with a precision of 8 and a scale of 4 can store up to 4 decimal places.

Perhaps the intention of the spec is to **display *at least* two decimal** places? e.g.

SQL DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE ClassEnrollement (
  OfferNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  StdNo NVARCHAR(9),
  EnrGrade DECIMAL(8, 4)
);
```

SQL DML:

```
SELECT OfferNo, StdNo, 
       FORMAT$(ClassEnrollement, '0.00##') 
          AS ClassEnrollement__formatted
  FROM ClassEnrollement;
```

Or perhaps the extra numeric scale is to enable custom rounding? The `DECIMAL` type exhibits rounding by trucation, a feature often missed because all other numeric types exhibit bankers' rounding. A rule of thumb is to store an extra place of numeric scale so that the inherent rounding, whatever it is, does not affect the raw value being stored, enabling custom rounding to be applied later. Two extra may simply be over-engineering ;)